# System / pip readline versions mismatch

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, readline, .so

I am using a python 3.6 virtual environment and am having problems with the readline package.
The system readline version is 8.0, while the pip package is

```
$ pip list | grep readline
gnureadline         6.3.8
```

This leads to trouble importing / using, i.e.:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Dec  7 2018, 08:11:04) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20180831] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Module readline not available.
>>> import readline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Since it's missing the .so, I tried downloading and building readline 7.0 from [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/readline/readline-7.0.tar.gz), and adding the directory with the `.so` to the path via

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/built/libreadline.so.7
```

With no effect, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out -- it seems that I can just make a symlink using the new version of readline, by:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libreadline.so.8.0 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.7
```